# Authorization header not working for angular 2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, cors, http-authentication, preflight

Hello I am using the Ionic 2 framework with Angular and I want to make a http request with the authorization header but it appears it is not sending the header. What have I done wrong?

```
    @Injectable()
export class UserServiceProvider {
  private loginSuccess: any;
  constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello UserServiceProvider Provider');
  }

  login(username, password)
  {
     var token = btoa(username + ':' + password);
     alert(token);
     this.loginSuccess = false;
     let headers = new Headers();
     headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + token);
     this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld/api/login/try', {
         headers: headers
     })
     .subscribe(function success(response) {
        this.loginSuccess = true;
     }, function error(response) {
        this.loginSuccess = false;
     });

     return this.loginSuccess;
  }
}
```

Here is the response in the browser console

```
polyfills.js:3 OPTIONS http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld/api/login/try 401 ()
s @ polyfills.js:3
t.scheduleTask @ polyfills.js:3
onScheduleTask @ polyfills.js:3
t.scheduleTask @ polyfills.js:3
r.scheduleTask @ polyfills.js:3
r.scheduleMacroTask @ polyfills.js:3
(anonymous) @ polyfills.js:3
o.(anonymous function) @ polyfills.js:2
(anonymous) @ http.es5.js:1275
Observable._trySubscribe @ Observable.js:171
Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:159
webpackJsonp.197.UserServiceProvider.login @ user-service.ts:29
webpackJsonp.196.AccountPage.login @ account.ts:21
(anonymous) @ AccountPage.html:25
handleEvent @ core.es5.js:12022
callWithDebugContext @ core.es5.js:13486
debugHandleEvent @ core.es5.js:13074
dispatchEvent @ core.es5.js:8615
(anonymous) @ core.es5.js:9226
(anonymous) @ platform-browser.es5.js:2651
t.invokeTask @ polyfills.js:3
onInvokeTask @ core.es5.js:3881
t.invokeTask @ polyfills.js:3
r.runTask @ polyfills.js:3
e.invokeTask @ polyfills.js:3
p @ polyfills.js:2
v @ polyfills.js:2
```

> (index):1 Failed to load
>   http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld/api/login/try: Response for preflight
>   has invalid HTTP status code 401

Comment: @Deniel McCarthy : Attach the screen shot of the request which is being send to server. One more point, it seems like you are doing login, if so, then in login the most used method is POST not the GET.

Comment: I have added the response to the post I don't think POST or GET will make a difference. This isn't a HTML form this is  Http Basic Authentication

Comment: Please check the CORS issue as preflight is failing.

Comment: @DanielMcCarthy Please check my edited answer where I have added a filter method to overcome CORS issue.

Comment: The error message shown in the question is for a response to a CORS preflight OPTIONS that the browser sent automatically on its own before even trying the GET request from your code. The CORS protocol requires that no credentials are included in a preflight OPTIONS request, so the browser didn’t send the Authorization header from your code. But the server you’re sending that request to is misconfigured to require authentication even for OPTIONS requests. So the server sends a 401 response rejecting the request and the preflight fails and the browser stops right there and never tries your GET.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the sample code of my project which I am using for login. Please refer the same for login. please check whether the login function in web service is GET or POST.

```
public postOAuthRequest(login:Login):Promise<any> {
    // Parameters obj-

    let params:URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    let headersvar = new Headers();

    params.set('username', login.userId.toString());
    params.set('password', login.password.toString());
    params.set('grant_type', 'password');
    params.set('scope', 'read write');
    params.set('client_secret', '123456');
    params.set('client_id', 'prithivi');
    var authdata = 'Basic ' + btoa('clientapp' + ':' + '412589');

    headersvar.append('accept', 'application/json');
    headersvar.append('Authorization', authdata);

    let requestOption:RequestOptionsArgs = {
        search: params,
        headers: headersvar,
        body: JSON.stringify({clientapp: 412589})
    };


    return this.http
        .post(OauthUrl, JSON.stringify({clientapp: 412589}), requestOption)
        .toPromise()
        .then(this.extractData)
}
```

Add a CORS filter method in web service to overcome CORS issue. Below code is in JAVA

```
 @Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT,DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3628800");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With, X-XSRF-TOKEN");
        if (!"OPTIONS".equals(request.getMethod())) {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        } else {
            response.setStatus(200);
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Where would I override doFIlter? In my rest controller?

Comment: create a new class and implement it with javax.servlet.filter interface.

Comment: So I can implement filter in any class that has a request mapping?

Comment: Filter class will be executed before service any request so it's good to create a separate class for the filter

Comment: What's the issue you are facing now?

Comment: I answered it scroll down to my answer

Comment: My rep is not high enough sorry

Answer (score -1):

Prithivi Raj helped solve my problem but it wasen't complete.
I used his code

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT,DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3628800");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With, X-XSRF-TOKEN");
        if (!"OPTIONS".equals(request.getMethod())) {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        } else {
            response.setStatus(200);
        }
}
```

You must create a filter that implements Filter and then in your web XML add

```
<filter>
     <filter-name>FilterName</filter-name>
        <filter-class>FilterPackage.FilterClass</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>FilterName</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Finally I assume the basic security configuration is being used so in your WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter your configure method should look like the code below. Basically you add a filter before the BasicAuthenticationFilter is activated solving the issue. If you do not do this and your login page uses authentication then your filter will only be called after authentication and by that point its too late

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterBefore(new CorsFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/login/try").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
                .antMatchers("/api/vehicles/manage/update").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
                .antMatchers("/api/vehicles/manage/create").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
                .antMatchers("/api/proposals/create").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
                .antMatchers("/api/proposals/cancel").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
                .antMatchers("/api/proposals/update").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
                .antMatchers("/api/proposals/accept").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
                .antMatchers("/api/upload").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();

    }
```

Thanks Prithivi Raj for your help!