# Error Ionic to access APIs

Tags: api, ionic-framework, ionic2

I tryed to access an API from Ionic, but I receive the error:

`Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 503.`

I've already tried using JSONP (with callback).

Comment: does your api have CORS enable. I also face same problem if I dont enable CORS in express.js api

Comment: Please check my answer and the thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/47052510/5782347

Comment: The problem is that I use an external API (api.instagram.com to be exact). There's no way I can change anything about it.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/41492870/5592752 - this should help